# Procedure pointer vs procedure name as argument of Fortran procedures

Tags: fortran

My understanding is that we can pass the information about which procedure should be used inside a Fortran procedure, either using an argument and declaring it to be a procedure name through a specific interface, or using an argument declared to be a procedure pointer.

I do not think I have grasped all pros and cons of the two alternatives. Maybe one has some limitations not present with the other? Are there efficiency issues?

---

Just to make clear what this question is about (if necessary), I'll briefly recall through two examples the different ways of passing information about which procedure should be used inside a procedure, through the procedure arguments.

1. **using an argument and declaring it to be a procedure name through a specific interface**

```
module pro
 implicit none
contains

 function myfunction(x) result(res) ! this is an actual function with the right signature to be used as argument of the subroutine prosub
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real :: res
    res = 2*x
 end function myfunction

 subroutine prosub(f,x)
   real, intent(in) :: x
   procedure(myfunction) :: f  ! the actual argument used in place of the dummy argument f must be the name of a function with the same signature as myfunction
   print*,f(x)
 end subroutine prosub
end module pro

program ppp
 use pro
 implicit none
 real :: x
 print*,' x= ?'
 read*,x
 call prosub(myfunction,x)
end program ppp
```

2. **using an argument declared to be a procedure pointer**

```
module pro
 implicit none
 abstract interface ! defines the signature of the functions the procedure pointers argument of the subroutine prosub must have
   function f(x) result(res)
     real, intent(in) :: x
     real :: res
   end function f
 end interface

contains

 function myfunction(x) result(res) ! one of the possible actual functions the procedure pointer can point to
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real :: res
    res = 2*x
 end function myfunction

 subroutine prosub(fp,x)
   real, intent(in) :: x
   procedure(f), pointer :: fp
   print*,fp(x)
 end subroutine prosub
end module pro

program ppp
 use pro
 implicit none
 real :: x
 procedure(f), pointer :: f1

 f1 => myfunction

 print*,' x= ?'
 read*,x
 call prosub(f1,x)
end program ppp
```

Comment: To ensure everyone (you, people answering, other people reading) is talking about the same things, please show (commented) examples of code using both forms you are wondering about.

Comment: @francescalus If my question was on a specific piece of code or a syntax issue, I agree with you. However, my question is about the possible differences of two (hopefully) well-known Fortran features. I refrain from adding an example to void that answers will focus on the example and not on the real issue. Would you give the same hint if I was asking about the pros and cons of pointers vs allocated arrays?

Comment: Pointers and allocatable arrays are fairly similar, but if you asked about the pros and cons of using a pointer dummy variable and an ordinary dummy variable I'd certainly want to make sure we're talking about the same things. You seem to be asking about non-pointer dummy procedures (akin to ordinary variables) and procedure pointer dummies (pointer variables). Nor is it obvious why "specific interface" is relevant in your mind for the non-pointer case but not for the pointer.

Comment: Consider, for example  `procedure(sub) a,b ; pointer b`. It's hard to give pros and cons even though these two dummies match your question: they are very different things.

Comment: @francescalus I have added two short examples. I hope that now the question is clear.

Comment: `f1` and `fp` are pointers; `myfunction` and `f` are not. That's a huge difference, and an obvious one, so I'm afraid I still don't see what pros and cons or limitations still interest you. Equally, I don't see why you don't consider `procedure(myfunction) :: f`. Perhaps others can, so I'll leave this for now.

Comment: @francescalus You are right, that is the simplest way, and I modified the first example accordingly. However, that's precisely the reason the original question did not contain an example. The question is not affected by the choice of this solution.  Of course, I know the obvious difference between a procedure pointer and a procedure. With the former, we can vary the pointed procedure everywhere, even inside prosub, we can't with the latter. But, from the point of view of the passage to prosub of the information about which function has to be used, both mechanisms reach the same goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dummy procedure pointer, when contrasted with a non-pointer dummy procedure, may (depending on argument intent and the like):

1. be passed in as disasssociated or undefined,
2. have its association status tested,
3. have its association status changed,
4. pass out information to the calling context.

If these capabilities are useful to have when writing a subprogram, then there might be a need for a dummy procedure pointer.

Specifying that something is a procedure pointer or non-pointer is orthogonal to how you specify the interface.  There is no semantic difference between a declaration of the form

```
procedure(some_interface) :: proc
```

and writing out an interface body for `proc` that has the same characteristics as `some_interface`. In your first "non-pointer" program, you could have equally written:

```
subroutine prosub(f,x)
  real, intent(in) :: x
  procedure(myfunction) :: f  ! or use the abstract interface
  print*,f(x)
end subroutine prosub
```

and in your second "pointer" program, you could have written:

```
subroutine prosub(fp,x)
  real, intent(in) :: x
 
  interface 
    function fp(x) result(res)
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real :: res
    end function fp
  end interface
  pointer :: fp
 
  print*,fp(x)
end subroutine prosub
```

This choice comes down to whether you want to specify the (perhaps abstract) interface in one location, or how much you like typing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It goes very close to what I was looking for. Do you know if, in practice, one can expect important efficiency issues with the resulting executable file?

Comment: If you *need* the capability of a procedure pointer, but don't use one, then there will likely be very significant efficiency issues, because you won't be able to create the executable.  If you don't need the capability of a procedure pointer, but you use one, then you may confuse future readers of your code.  I don't expect any material runtime differences, but you need to measure for your program with your compiler on your computer.  In terms of declaration style - lots of typing might not be efficient, depending on your keyboarding skills.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this. You would use a procedure pointer dummy argument if what you're passing to it is a procedure pointer. Procedure pointers are typically used in data structures where the choice of which to call is determined at run-time. If instead you will always be passing a procedure name, you may as well declare the dummy as a procedure (with an interface).

Now, this answer would be clear in the pre-F2008 era. However, F2008 allows an `INTENT(IN), POINTER` dummy to be associated with a non-pointer actual, if the actual is a valid pointer assignment target. Given this, you could make the dummy a pointer if you wanted to with no difference in semantics.

Edit: Here's a small example of passing a procedure name to a procedure pointer.

```
module foo_m
abstract interface
subroutine p_int
end subroutine p_int
end interface
contains
subroutine foo (p)
procedure(p_int), intent(in), pointer :: p
call p
end subroutine foo
end module foo_m

program test
use foo_m
call foo (my_p)
contains
subroutine my_p
print *, "Hi from my_p"
end subroutine my_p
end program test
```

Comment: Thanks. The part on post-F2008 is new to me. How an actual procedure can be made a valid pointer assignment target?

Comment: As long as the actual procedure has a compatible interface with the pointer, it's a valid target. I'll edit my response to include a complete example.